# Getting column value from Browser

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have one browser displaying customer details. When I select one row (ie one customer) in that browser I want to get the Customer Number of that customer.So that I can populate another browser "OrderBrowser" which will display the order of the selected Customer.How?

Comment: on mouse-select-click of customerbrowse
    do:
       FIND CURRENT Customer.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     end.                                                                                         I got this answer. My question was about "find current" now I got it thanks for replies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a trigger

```
ON VALUE-CHANGED OF BrowserHandle DO:
  your code
END.
```

Comment: can you tell what is the difference in using value-changed and mouse-select-click ?

Comment: value-changed response on each change of row selection. no matter if selected with mouse or with a keyboard or from script.